# How to verify Firebase Auth id token in Vercel edge functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, vercel

Firebase admin SDK is not supported on [Vercel edge functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/limitations#most-node.js-apis-are-not-available) so how can I [authenticate client requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) and get Firebase user object (uid, email, name, custom claims) from id token?

There's this intro (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) to verify id tokens using third-party libraries but that's just it.

Comment: As advised on the documentation you linked, use the [`jose`](https://github.com/panva/jose) or [`jsrsasign`](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign) packages. Both are compatible with the Vercel Edge runtime.

Comment: I can't get the final step to work: Finally, ensure that the ID token was signed by the private key corresponding to the token's kid claim. Grab the public key from https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com and use a JWT library to verify the signature. Use the value of max-age in the Cache-Control header of the response from that endpoint to know when to refresh the public keys.

If all the above verifications are successful, you can use the subject (sub) of the ID token as the uid of the corresponding user or device.

Comment: I tried verifying the signature on  https://jwt.io/ and it comes invalid.

Answer (score 3):

The following library module makes use of [`jose`](https://github.com/panva/jose) to handle the verification of the token. It has been coded freehand, so expect typos. The module exposes two methods: `verifyIdToken(req: NextRequest, firebaseIdToken: string)` (that rejects on error) and `verifyIdTokenWithInlineError(req: NextRequest, firebaseIdToken: string)` (that never rejects, instead returning the error in the returned object). Use the one that suits your style.

**Note:** This code does not currently check in with Firebase Auth to see if the token has been revoked.

```js
// lib/verify-jwt.ts
import * as jose from 'jose';

// Builds a callback function that makes API calls to the given endpoint
// only once the last response expires, otherwise a fresh call is made.
const buildCachedFetch = (src: string) => {
  let _cache = false,
    expiresAt = 0,
    init = async () => {
      const nowMS = Date.now(),
        res = await fetch(src);
      if (!res.ok) {
        const err = new Error("Unexpected response status code: " + res.status);
        err.res = res;
        throw err;
      }
      expiresAt = nowMS + (Number(/max-age=(\d+)/.exec(res.headers.get('cache-control'))?.[1] || 0) * 1000);
      return res.json();
    },
    refresh = () => {
      expiresAt = 0;
      _cache = init();
      _cache.catch(() => _cache = null);
      return _cache
    };
  
  return (forceRefresh?: boolean) => {
    return !forceRefresh && _cache && (expiresAt === 0 || expiresAt > Date.now())
      ? _cache
      : refresh()
  }
}

// build the callback to fetch the authentication certificates
const fetchAuthKeyStore = buildCachedFetch("https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com");

// Defines a callback to pass to the JWT verifier to resolve the appropriate public key
const authKeyResolver = async ({ alg: string, kid: string }) => {
  const keyStore = await fetchAuthKeyStore();
  if (!(kid in keyStore)) throw new Error("unexpected kid in auth token")
  return jose.importX509(keyStore[kid], alg);
};

// Verifies the Authorization header and returns the decoded ID token. Errors
// will reject the Promise chain.
export const verifyIdToken = async (req: NextRequest, firebaseProjectId: string) => {
  const jwt = /^bearer (.*)$/i.exec(req.headers.get('authorization'));
  
  if (!jwt) throw new Error("Unauthorised");
  
  const result = jose.jwtVerify(jwt, authKeyResolver, {
    audience: firebaseProjectId,
    issuer: `https://securetoken.google.com/${firebaseProjectId}`
  });
  
  result.payload.uid = result.payload.sub; // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.decodedidtoken.md#decodedidtokenuid
  
  return result;
}

// Verifies the Authorization header and returns the decoded ID token. Errors
// are returned in the return object instead of rejecting the Promise chain.
export const verifyIdTokenWithInlineError = (req: NextRequest, firebaseProjectId: string) => {
  return verifyIdToken(req, firebaseProjectId)
    .catch((error) => ({ error, payload: null, protectedHeader: null }));
}
```

Using Vercel's `hello.ts` example as a base, you would use it like so:

```js
// pages/api/hello.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { verifyIdTokenWithInlineError } from '../../lib/verify-jwt';

export const config = {
  runtime: 'edge', // this is a pre-requisite
  regions: ['iad1'], // only execute this function on iad1
};

const FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = "<your-project-id>";

export default async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const { error, payload } = await verifyIdTokenWithInlineError(req, FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID);
  
  if (error) {
    return NextResponse.status(403).json({
      error: "You must be authenticated.",
    });
  }

  // if here, a valid auth token was provided. `payload` contains some
  // user info.

  return NextResponse.json({
    name: `Hello ${payload.name}! I'm an Edge Function!`,
  });
};
```